# How to get a model position in Gazebo World Plugin?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am writing a Gazebo World Plugin where I need an information about the position of certain model with respect to world origin. I am using Gazebo-9 and for this version of Gazebo I didn't find any working solution. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21453/how-to-get-a-model-position-in-gazebo-world-plugin?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
// Get model
auto model = _world->ModelByName("model_name");
// Get pose
auto pose = model->WorldPose();
```

Checking the API documentation should help you in the future:

- http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html
- http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2